# Auto-Generation of a Pojo according to the Excel sheet by Java

Tags: java, excel, api, pojo

Is there any way to auto-generate a Dynamic POJO as per the columns available in Excel Sheet?

Example: If an Excel Sheet contains 10 Columns and 15 rows, I want a Pojo having 10 String array variables and with the size of array should be 15.

any clew will be helpful.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you please elaborate more on this. I think you can directly use List of List or List of Maps for the scenario.

Comment: True.I want to put all the cells of a row in an object. my base class contains the methods corresponding to each column of the Excel sheet. Lets say, the Excel contains column name such as Name, Age, Sex. The setter and getter of those variables in POJO will be getName() & setName(), getAge() & setAge() AND getSex() & setSex(), whose object can exactly exteneded and type-casted to my base class. But it is NOT possible if its List or Map.

Comment: For this to work, your getter and setters should be defined at the compile time, so you have to know the names of the spreadsheet columns, or their possible superset, beforehand. If you are not going to rely on the compiler, I don't see any material difference between accessing methods via reflection and using methods like `getProperty(String name)` and `setProperty(String name, String value)`, except the later approach is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a tool (e.g. a Maven plugin) which takes an Excel sheet and generates code from it. Such a tool should not be very complicated and could be useful. However the usual way of achieving something like this is to specify your data structures in an XSD and generate the code from it, for example using [JAXB](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/). So IMO you need a compelling argument to generate code from Excel instead of an XSD to warrant writing a tool for it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin that is created for this specific purpose. It takes an excel sheet and creates POJO from them. But you'll have to arrange the columns in a specific way for it to work properly. Add the following in you pom and put the excel sheet in the resources directory, change the plugin configuration to replace the excel.xlsx with the name of your excel sheet .

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.pkoli</groupId>
        <artifactId>xls2pojo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <fileName>target/classes/excel.xlsx</fileName>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>xls2pojo</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

The plugin assumes the first column to be the class name, the second to be the variable name and the third as the datatype. So if an excel sheet contains data in the following way -

[image: Example]

The following POJO's are generated -

```
public class Student {
public String name;
public double marks;
public int rollno;
}


public class Teacher {
public String name;
}
```